# Why Can't the Wheel Event Be Done Over the Iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, mousewheel

Hope You All Have A Good Day Today!

The story is starts since I develop my own website. I want it to be tabbed and fullpaged, but scrollable too. So, i think the only solution to be scrollable is use the `wheel` event to change the page, which inside every page container contained `iframe` except my first page. Why `iframe`? Because I want it to be lighter by load the `src` only when the we direct to the page we want to see, so on pageload it loads the empty `iframe`.

But, another story begins when I frustated to develop my own `wheel` event based tab and started to use PagePilingJS by @Alvaro. I try it out in my codepen with normal `div` and not containing anything and it's normally worked. But, when I use the `iframe` inside the `div`, it becomes unscrollable. So, I'm going back to my own `wheel` event based tab, and when I use the `iframe` inside the `div`, the issue is the same. Here's the code I wrote in Codepen :

```js
//Add & remove class tab, contents, & menu onclick & wheel
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ()=> {
    let tabs = document.querySelectorAll('.tab');
    let content = document.querySelectorAll('.content');
    let firstTab = function(tabs) {tabs.classList.add('tab-active')};
    let firstContent = function(content) {content.classList.add('content-active')};
    let activeTab = 0;
  
    firstTab(tabs[0]);
    firstContent(content[0]);
        
    for (let i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {            
        tabs[i].addEventListener('click', () => tabClick(i));
        }

    function detect(e) {
        var delta = null,
            direction = false;
        if(!e) {e = window.event;}
        if(e.wheelDelta) {delta = e.wheelDelta / 60;
        } else if(e.detail) {delta = -e.detail / 2;}
        if(delta !== null) {
            direction = delta > 0 ? 'up' : 'down';}
        return direction;
    }

    function handle(direction) { //mousewheel to change tabs
        console.log(direction);
        if(direction == 'down') {
            if(activeTab >= tabs.length - 1) {
            activeTab = 0;
            tabClick(activeTab);
            } else {
            tabClick(activeTab + 1);
            }
        } else if(direction == 'up') {
            if(activeTab === 0) {
            activeTab = tabs.length - 1;
            tabClick(activeTab);
            } else {
            tabClick(activeTab - 1);
            }
            } else {
            // this means the direction of the mouse wheel could not be determined
        }
    }
    document.onmousewheel = function(e) {handle(detect(e));};
    if(window.addEventListener) {document.addEventListener
    ('DOMMouseScroll', function(e) {handle(detect(e));});
    }

        
        function tabClick(currentTab) {
          removeActive();
            //Add Active Class
            tabs[currentTab].classList.add('tab-active');
            content[currentTab].classList.add('content-active');
            activeTab = currentTab;
        }  
        function removeActive() {
          for(let i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
           if(content[i].classList.contains('content-active'),
              tabs[i].classList.contains('tab-active')) {
            //Remove Active Class
            content[i].classList.remove('content-active');
            content[i].classList.add('content-show');
            setTimeout(function() {
              content[i].classList.remove('content-show');
            },1500);
            tabs[i].classList.remove('tab-active');
           }
          }
         }
       })
```

```css
        /* WHOLE CONTAINER */
        .container {
          width: 96vw;
          height: 96vh;
        }
        
        /* TABS */
        .tabs {
            display: flex;
            height: 50px;
            overflow: hidden;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .tab {
            font-size: 14px;
            padding: 5px 10px;
            cursor: pointer;
            letter-spacing: 2px;
            text-alignment: center;
        }

        #red.tab-active {background-color: rgb(245, 66, 66);}
        #blue.tab-active {background-color: rgb(66, 135, 245);}
        #yellow.tab-active {background-color: rgb(245, 215, 66);}
        #green.tab-active {background-color: rgb(56, 235, 98);}
        #cyan.tab-active {background-color: rgb(79, 247, 219);}


        /* TAB CONTENTS */
        .contents {
            width: 100%;
            margin-top: 5px;
            height: 80%;
        }

        .content {
            width: 96%;
            height: 80%;
            display: none;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            border: none;
            position: absolute;
        }

        .content-show {
            display: flex;
            animation-name: fade-out;
            animation-duration: 2.5s;
        }
        
        @keyframes fade-out {
            0% {
                opacity: 1;
                display: flex;
            }
            99% {
                opacity: 0;
                display: flex;
            }
            100% {
                opacity: 0;
                display: none;
            }
        }

        .content-active {
            display: flex;
            border: none;
            justify-content: center;
            animation-name: fade-in;
            animation-duration: 2.5s;
        }
        
        .content-iframe {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            border: none;
        }

        @keyframes fade-in {
            0% {
                display: none;
                opacity: 0;
            }
            1% {
                display: block;
                opacity: 0.01;
            }
            100%{
                display: block;
                opacity: 1;
            }
        }

        #red.content-active {background-color: rgb(245, 66, 66);}
        #blue.content-active {background-color: rgb(66, 135, 245);}
        #yellow.content-active {background-color: rgb(245, 215, 66);}
        #green.content-active {background-color: rgb(56, 235, 98);}
        #cyan.content-active {background-color: rgb(79, 247, 219);}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="tabs">
       <div id="red" class="tab">RED</div>
       <div id="blue" class="tab">BLUE</div>
       <div id="yellow" class="tab">YELLOW</div>
       <div id="green" class="tab">GREEN</div>
       <div id="cyan" class="tab">CYAN</div>
   </div>

   <div class="contents">
       <div id="red" class="content">
         <iframe id="iframec" class= "content-iframe" data-src="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokyo" src="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokyo" loading="lazy" scrolling="no"></iframe>
       </div>
       <div id="blue" class="content"></div>
       <div id="yellow" class="content"></div>
       <div id="green" class="content"></div>
       <div id="cyan" class="content"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

So, the question is :

**Why Can't the Wheel Event Be Done Over the Iframe?**

Comment: Look at this line in your HTML:          `<iframe id="iframec" class= "content-iframe" data-src="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokyo" src="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokyo" loading="lazy" scrolling="no"></iframe>` ... try change **scrolling to "yes"**

Comment: That's not what I mean. Although I change it to 'yes', It won't change to another tab. You can try it in FullPage JS or PagePiling JS , which use the `wheel` event, you'll be occuring the same issue @toffler

Comment: Oh, I see - you want to scroll through your tabs. 
It works for me, once you hover your tabs with your mouse.

Comment: Try hover the iframe, then scroll it. Can it be done?? @toffler

Comment: In Edge and Chrome it's working on my side once you hover the tabs

Comment: The tab or the content? @toffler